# I can't make a query select into in 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert

"Make a query that having all orders by employees from employeeUK in the orderUK table"

my table of employeeUK:

```
select *
into employeeUK
from Employees
where Country = 'UK'
```

then i want to make the orderUK table but i got confuse because my query always error.
How the query should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is are you creating a Temp Table to a Perm table.  Does the Table already exist or not.

If you are creating a temp table use the following

```
Select * 
Into #employeeUK
From Employees
Where Country = 'UK'
```

If this is going into a Perm table you can use the same code as long as the table does not already exist.

If the table already exist then use this code.

```
Insert Into employeeUK
Select * 
From Employees
Where Country = 'UK'
```

Remember Temp Tables start with a '#' perm tables do not.

Answer (score 0):

you have to start with the table you going to insert the data into.

```
into employeeUK
select *
from Employees
where Country = 'UK'
```